# Pressing brake makes a fast clicking sound and the brake pedal jumps

Tags: toyota, brakes, camry

I have 1999 camry. Just replaced bearing  and axle.  Now when pressing brake it makes a fast clicking sound and  the brake pedal jumps. What would  cause this????

Comment: Re-check your work, something was assembled improperly, most likely with the brake parts, rotor,pad,caliper

Comment: It sounds like the ABS is coming on when you press the brake.  Have you damaged/disturbed an abs sensor?

Answer (score 2):

There is an ABS wire connected to the strut. It goes to a sensor located just within the spindle (This is why you have the gear like notches on the axle). This wire should run up into the fender well to the ABS computer. If you damaged the wire the ABS will literally freak out and this is one of the first symptoms. A visual inspection first, and then a computer analysis to test functionality should yield results.

Next to that, I would make sure you followed standard caliper/pad/rotor replacement protocol.

- Grease caliper pins upon reassembly
- Use a torque wrench to ensure you haven't over torqued anything
- Make sure that all parts marked for a specific side went on that specific side.
- Make sure you installed pads with the indicator strips on the correct side. This will often cause a loud clicking and can cause ABS to fail.